# WPF DataGrid Vertical Line Thickness

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I've added a [DataGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx) to my WPF Window, and I've set the [VerticalGridLinesBrush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.verticalgridlinesbrush(v=vs.110).aspx) property in the XAML to show the vertical grid lines in the relevant colour. But I can't figure out how to increase width of the vertical grid lines, that are displayed in the [DataGridRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridrow(v=vs.110).aspx).

Can someone please show me how to set the vertical grid line thickness in a WPF DataGrid?

Answer (score 5):

set this properties

**GridLinesVisibility="All" ,  VerticalGridLinesBrush="Red" and BorderThickness="1,1,5,0"**

in dataGrid.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is no thickness setting for the GridLines... you can probably use `DataGridCell` properties instead.

```
    <DataGrid GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal">
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,3,0"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```